# extracting values from json file using ijson

Tags: python, json, yajl, ijson

I have a large JSON file which looks like this :

```
{"details":{

    "1000":[
        ["10","Thursday","1","19.89"],

        ["12","Monday","3","20.90"],
        ...
    ]
    "1001":[
        ["30","Sunday","11","80.22"],

        ["88","Wednesday","22","8.29"],
        ...
    ]

    }
}
```

Now I'm extracting the lists present in variables like "1000", "1001" from the "**details**" value using **ijson** (Interactive Json)  using code given below :

```
import ijson as ijson
filename='Clean_Details.json'

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    objects=ijson.items(f,'details.1001.item')
    for row in objects:
        print(row)
    print("Done")
```

But the Problem is that : **for the loop is not terminating** in the above code. After printing the final list in 1001 it keeps running.

I'm guessing that the the Generator(**objects**) in above code is not encountering the **StopIteration** don't know why.

Could Anyone help?
A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a real case file for testing? Using the sample file i couldn't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as it turns out because of *large size* of **JSON** file which is > **800MB** with about more than a million records the parsing takes time to complete so it

The loop terminates eventually but takes some time to complete. On a pc with normal specs it definitely takes some time.

Also using :

```
import ijson as ijson
```

is way slower on very large files because most of the parsing takes place using python backend code so inorder to improve the speed,

It is way better to use

```
import ijson.backends.yajl2_cffi as ijson
```

because it has a backend in C language using *cffi* which does improves running time for the above code.

Comment: Apparently some issue with the "cffi" module? This is the error message I received.      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ijson/backends/yajl2_cffi.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cffi import FFI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cffi'